# CSS Transition a background-color from 50% to 100% on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a simple ease-in-out transition on hover where the background colour increases from 50% of the viewport to 100% of the viewport.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #999;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }

      .container:hover{
        /* width: 100% */
        }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried numerous combinations but cannot get a smooth transition. Is there a straight forward way to do this with a css transition or do I need to be looking towards using Javascript?

Comment: you want the background-color to increase from 50% to 100%?! I think you have mixed-up width with background-color. please elaborate your problem.

Comment: Sorry @pouria I am trying to achieve an effect where to start with the left hand 50% of the viewport is grey and then on hover the grey background transitions to cover 100% of the viewport over for example 0.5s.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. But if you remove the comment from `/* width: 100% */`, the grey box fills the screen with an animation.

Comment: Your snippet does work when you uncomment it? P.S. add in the compatibility though : ` -moz-transition`  /  `-webkit-transition`   /  `-o-transition`  /   `transition` :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Thank you both. I'm not sure why it wasn't working before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #999;
        transition: all 0.70s ease-in-out;
      }

      .container:hover{
        width: 100%
        }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this is a smooth transition.